# Exception Handling issue in user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a page that has 2 user controls. 
I am doing `Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx")` in Global.asax page in Application_Error.

It works for all the pages but when an exception comes in a user control, the page is not getting redirected to ErrorPage. If I redirect in the catch block in the user control itself, programs works perfect. What am i doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Do you have any ajax update panel in there?

Comment: One control is in update panel. But not the control that is throwing an exception.

Comment: What happens if you pass `true` as the second argument to `Response.Redirect`? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I tried passing true, but the page is still crashing